# Write to and read from .txt file, listselectionlistener

Tags: java, actionlistener, jlist, listselectionlistener

I need some help making this program write the `JList` elements info to a `.txt` file and then outputing the contents of the `.txt` file to the textarea instead of just outputing the `JList` elements info directly in to the textarea.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.System.*;

  public class ListModel extends JFrame {

   private JList list;
   private DefaultListModel model;
   private JTextField inputf;
   private JTextField inpute;
   private JTextArea text;
   private JPanel p1;
   private JPanel p2;
   private ListSelectionModel ListSelectionModel;

    public ListModel() {
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
      list = new JList(model);

      JButton addButton = new JButton( "Lägg till" );
      model.addElement("Kajsa Åslund");
      model.addElement("Erik Carlsson");
      model.addElement("John Åkesson");
      model.addElement("Per-arne Ingvarsson");
      model.addElement("Rebecka Asp");
      model.addElement("Linnéa Åslund");
      model.addElement("Åsa-Nisse Strong");
      model.addElement("Super Lasse");
      model.addElement("Alexander Ahl");
      model.addElement("Ann Ahl");
      model.addElement("Bo Sten");
     addButton.addActionListener(
     new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
                     {
                     final String name=inputf.getText() + " " + inpute.getText();

                     model.addElement( name );
                 }
             }
             );
     JButton removeButton =
     new JButton( "Ta bort" );

     removeButton.addActionListener(
     new ActionListener() {

         public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
             {
             setTitle("Borttagning");
             try
            {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
             model.removeElement(list.getSelectedValue());
             setTitle("Personer");
         }
     }
     );
     text = new JTextArea(5, 20);
     text.setEditable(false);

     inputf = new JTextField();
     inputf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }

    });
     inpute = new JTextField();
     inpute.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }

    });

     list.setModel(model);
     list.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new             ListSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            text.setText(list.getSelectedValue().toString());
        }
     });

     inpute.setBounds(5, 5, 100, 100);
     inpute.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,20));
     inputf.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 150);
     inputf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,20));
     JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(list);
     scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));

     JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
     p2.add(text);
     p2.add(inputf);
     p2.add(inpute);
     p2.add(addButton);
     p2.add(removeButton);
     p2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p2,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

     JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
     p1.add(scroll);


     Container container = getContentPane();
     container.add(p1);
     container.add(p2);
     container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

     setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
     setSize( 500, 250 );
     setVisible( true );
 }

   public static void main( String args[] )
         {
         new ListModel();
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Or is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using for example `BufferedWriter()` and `BufferedReader()`, which are one of the basic java I/O API, and you can read about them [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html). It is worth to learn to use it.

To write a content of `model` to .txt file you can use loop, like this one:

```
for(Object string : model.toArray()){
   out.write(t + "\n");    // "out" is BufferedWriter object
}
```

`toArray()` will take a data form `model`, and store it in an `Object[]` array. Then you can extract it with `for each` loop, and write into a file.
This will print a `model` content as a list inside .txt file, one name in one line.

Then, you can read it using `BufferedReader()`, line after line, an add avery line directly to `JTextArea`.

**BTW**. I think you ramove option does't work as it should. It is because, you need to select a item to remove it. But when you select it, `ListSelectionListener()` try to read a data form list, and throw `NullPointerException()` when item is removed. In effect it behave wierd. To fix it, it is enough to modify `valueChanged()`:

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    if(list.getSelectedValue()!=null) text.setText(list.getSelectedValue().toString());
}
```

It will read data from list, only it is not `null` (in other words removed).

Comment: But how do i put the Buffered writer and reader in the listselectionlistener? I suppose that's what i have to do since the process has to be repeated every time a new element is highlighted. Sorry if these are dumb questions, i'm relatively new to programming. But i really appreciate the help you're giving me :)

Comment: Maybe you understood what i asked originally or maybe i'm the one at fault here, maybe I misunderstood what you wrote. But doesn't what you describe add data to the list from the .txt file? Because my goal is to add the data of the list to the .txt file and then output the data from the .txt file to the textarea, as well as saving the textfile with the data in.

Comment: @AntonMehlqvist you are totally right, my mistake. However I understood that you want something like a save/load option.So what is you goal here? you want to write one selected list element to file, every time you select something, and then retrive one element to JTextArea? or you want to have all Strings from file displayed on JTextArea? Could you please give some more details?